# matlab read excel and fetch rows containing search term

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-guide

I am reading excel file

```
[num, txt, raw] =  xlsread('D://qq.xls','D1');
```

Above code is reading data in sheet D1. Excel sheet looks life this
[image]

I want to fetch and display only those rows with search term provided by user. Search term will be from **diagnosis** column(last column).

For eg.
If user wants Data of diagnosis with term "**PD**".

How can we get that?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Here is the code:

```
[num, txt, raw] =  xlsread('D://qq.xls','D1','B2:HH24');// read excel file
B = raw.'; // transpose it
qq=B(1:end, 23);//get diagnosis column
x = strmatch('NODB', qq);//find match for cell array it returns row index
qq=B(x, :); //fetch data from row index
```

Thank you:)